# Combine dictionaries with the same keys value

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionaries like this.

```
dicts = [
 {"key_a": "2022-01-30",
  "key_b": "54",
  "key_c": "3"},

 {"key_a": "2022-01-30", 
  "key_b": "46", 
  "key_c": "2"},

 {"key_a": "2022-01-04",
  "key_b": "32",
  "key_c": "4"}

 {"key_a": "2022-01-30",
  "key_b": "2",
  "key_c": "10"}
]

# check same value of key_a
# Sum key_b 
# keep the first key_c value from the dictionaries
```

I want to merge those with same "date". I tried with Panda but I am looking for a more simple way

This is the ouput I am looking for

```
new_dicts = [
 {"key_a": "2022-01-30",
  "key_b": "102",
  "key_c": "3"},

 {"key_a": "2022-01-04",
  "key_b": "32",
  "key_c": "4"}
]
```

Comment: What happens to key_c when you "add"? Is it added too?

Comment: We keep the first key_c value from the list so '3' in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_dicts(dicts):
    dates = {d["key_a"] for d in dicts}
    for date in dates:
        yield {
            "key_a": date,
            "key_b": str(sum(map(int, d["key_b"] for d in dicts if d["key_a"] == date))),
            "key_c": next(d["key_c"] for d in dicts if d["key_a"] == date)
        }

print(list(get_dicts(dicts)))
```

Comment: I edited my question. Numbers are between "

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas`, it's not too difficult.

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
d.groupby("key_a", as_index=False).agg({"key_b":lambda x: sum(int(a) for a in x),
                                        "key_c":"first"}).to_dict(orient="records")

# [{'key_a': '2022-01-04', 'key_b': 32, 'key_c': '4'},
#  {'key_a': '2022-01-30', 'key_b': 102, 'key_c': '3'}]
```

Comment: Thank yo, that does the job and it seems it is the easier way.